# Uncaught Exception: SQLSTATE[42000] при вставке

Tags: mysql, sql

Запрос:

```
INSERT INTO desc (`title`,`desc`) VALUE ('sdfg','sdfg')
```

Ошибка:

> Uncaught Exception: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
>   1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'desc (`title`,`desc`) VALUE ('sdfg','sdfg')'

Comment: А если название таблицы тоже в кавычки взять как и названия столбцов?

Comment: Мне кажется наоборот. Названия столбцов не брать в кавычки. На это и ругается

Comment: убрал, не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рабочий вариант на php - протестировал.

```
$servername = "0.0.0.0";
$username = "640";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "DBNAME";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'");
mysqli_query($conn, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

$sql21 = "INSERT into desс (title, desс) values('Это','Работает')";
$result21 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql21);

print_r($conn);
```

Вот запись в БД. https://pastenow.ru/46946206cedf96f03bc4378802b26cf1

Comment: Та же ошибка, даже когда убираю кавычки.

Comment: Изменил ответ и протестировал.

Comment: У меня еще у самого в таблице была ошибка. Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Переименуйте таблицу и колонки. desc - зарезервированное слово, применяется в момент сортировки (asc, desc)

Список зарезервированных слов https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-D

Настоятельно не рекомендую использовать зарезервированные слова. Более того смотреть зарезервированные слова лучше во всех основных БД (MySql, PotgreSql, Oracle, MS SQL) на случай возникновения необходимости миграции с одной БД на другую. Даже если в данном конкретном случае этот момент удастся обойти, то дальше будут большие проблемы.

Comment: Спасибо, сработало.

Comment: Z.Hohn Не в этом дело. Посмотрите мой пример, он рабочий, хотя там и таблица и столбец называются desc

Comment: Читайте документацию- ошибка ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax именно из-за использования ключевых слов. Ни про какой php в вопросе ничего не было и это не означает что это будет работать во всех языках.